# Installing ruby-1.9.3-p545 stuck

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, homebrew

I want to run a rails app which prompts the following, when I `cd` in the repo:

```
rake ruby-1.9.3-p545 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p545'
```

I currently use ruby-2.1.1, but for some reason I get an error and I just want to see if it's the ruby version that is the problem.
When I run `rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p545` the process starts and gets stuck on `Installing required packages: gcc46`. It's been on this step for more than 3 hours now and I doubt it will change.

I tried to install gcc46 from homebrew with `brew install gcc46`.  This is the output:

```
==> Downloading http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/gcc/gcc-4.6.4/gcc-4.6.4.tar.bz2
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/gcc46-4.6.4.tar.bz2
==> ../configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc46/4.6.4 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++ --program-suffix=-4.6 --with-gmp=/usr/local/opt/gmp4 --with-mpfr=/usr/local/opt/mpfr2 --with-mpc=/usr/local/opt/libmpc08 --with-ppl=/usr/local/opt/ppl011 --with-cloog=/usr/local/opt/cloog-ppl015 --with-system-zlib --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-stage1-checking --enable-checking=release --enable-lto --disable-werror --enable-plugin --disable-nls --enable-multilib
==> make bootstrap
```

And then the same - nothing happens for hours.

Comment: i havent used mac but usually do 'rvm install 1.9.3' to install 1.9.3 on ubuntu.

Comment: No difference. The outcome is the same.

Answer (score 5):

The problem seems to be `gcc46`.

You can try this:
`rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p545 --with-gcc=clang` to use Clang instead and see if that helps.

Comment: I managed to install it already, by first installing gcc47 manually and then install ruby 1.9.3. It didn't require the requirement of gcc46 this time and it all went smoothly. Still, installing gcc47 took me around 90 minutes...

Answer (score 1):

trust me. Just be patient.  I have the same feeling. After waiting for almost 20 mins, I saw,

> ==> ../configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.3 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++ --program-suffix=-4.8 --with-gmp=/usr/local/opt/gmp4 --with-mpfr=/usr/local/opt/mpfr2 --with-mpc=/usr/local/opt/libmpc08 --with-cloog=/usr/local/opt/cloog018 --with-isl=/usr/local/opt/isl011 --with-system-zlib --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-stage1-checking --enable-checking=release --enable-lto --disable-werror --with-pkgversion=Homebrew gcc48 4.8.3 --with-bugurl=https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions/issues --enable-plugin --disable-nls --enable-multilib
>   ==> make bootstrap
>   ==> make install
>     /usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.3: 1028 files, 142M, built in 21.9 minutes